# How to get proper tree view of Microsoft 365 Outlook email hiararchy?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

I am using Microsoft 365 Outlook, and I want to see the full hierarchy of an email tree: who's replied to exactly which email, so I can prune appropriately. I am sure this used to be possible in an earlier version of Outlook (maybe 3 years ago), but if I set the emails to conversation then there seems to be no option to do this. I can set to "classic indented view" but that's not what I'm looking for.

Currently, the relevant emails in a complex chain just seem to appear in a semi-random order - not even entirely time-sequenced, and certainly not with the neat hierarchy view that used to be possible.

Answer (score 1):

When we moved from Office 2010 to Office 2013 we seemed to have lost that functionality.  At least I have not been able to find it.